# Why can adding a superfluous conditional change TypeScript's compilation?

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, conditional-types

In [this TypeScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQHJwGZQiOAiARgOwDoArAZ2wG4AoKgeloGVQwAbYVYAUwBM4A3TlFLAI+OBFRxOADxiD8AQxYsAnmmDSecEBG6cWFbQvxqO+7qXEhgMOb1TQ4w8C0FTpCl5yowVYTnAAYlws3EienADqNgAWAGpKAK6cALIKYHAAvHAA3lRwBXApEKIAXHAA2mah4SCc5dh8wMK4rgwwCkIAwhCJ+DDYADTq5gksyeXIALpwAD6V1WERDTEQpDDtnUMjoWMTTjBQwPgA5lPUhXAACizGnDDlVSFLdQ1NLW0d3b3924t79UQSBm8ye5lqgOwq3WNzuA2G-ySgPWR1O5yoAF86LRfP5rrd8PdOioELoVBCsnAANacFQSILPCHRGDxJFpMCGegAcmKoi5czgXNhhJgXMM+Ag8ESpC0DigTmYrnlMk8rG8uICABVEmrNRAAPK4YicADGMAAPJr3HJ8BZKijjidhsYVFMAHyUnKVGlqY5wTUVAAMUym5QAorIoAozZbhhUfc6TO6KgBGGYY6j0AASEAEqJO4jzcBZnBlxYA7hB3KrXKRhiXi35S3BOgEFJYZP4zTxDCW1IStDAq7gAnojgJ7BgsMxoHZG-5SIQfE2iiV8IbjWaU5TtbqDUbTRbguCIszWeNUukKjy11z3ZzaDl3sBWpxNt8+g8gYZoTBhfdygdU4KCxDV8ThDdD23bJd1cPVIJjY8alPWIAXZa9-1Fe84HoJ9mhfT5OlIHpP0mJAfzWDYvkAw5HRAmgwNgzh4IPM1IijMB-CgS1rU4W1LBvPkBSFAl7i5D0YJ1OD903I9GRQlk0KvTV72xABVYRTmLGIAlIHVBFQcZelIABaE1RG4GwREUFh+EEYRRDgEcWAgcs4GOdZOAUXh6QbBRcFzAJKygKk6ycxJ4HLGIVAAfmxRipOYmTD3Y9IuJ4mQbTtQT8H5eYRLhcTKQACitTK+Oy3lcrgGL-USljZPNJCXiiVC2WU904HKJiGsPJr5LqM8lLACoVLdABKahlzxBCYGKPQWAy2QKoEqq8sFTCiskvdZtSzjBEtN1M1oDTHW03T9KgQzEmMsyLKs0QlDsoRrKc-RXPc-BPO88RJD8gKBDgYLQuGXAIqB6K4voMDZvm-Qlqy1bb2EzaJLgUreP4wU1pquqdtYmA9vSzUPW6+rkrYjjiYm46czzM7AvlEsyxgSt6x0tRWxbDtpC7OcADI4AlOc-XMkA6n6SxpTOzhYjcPMHLEelYd0fQcLx6TdqpwRSmmgIqtmgAmSkVYW80cvEh88I+N8vmIn4v2QCiYVEr8gJOeiwMwo2TYJuHFoKkVLZwx9n1fd97dI784F-d8aPzei9bgAARAAlABNU39HZT18kKCpMOJUluBULpblISw-R9elmqZNqL3ZUM4CzxbC6gEkyTL9tSDdPOCnoTUdLely3OBsKwfgYXzpbAHOETXgoE4ABHRJgEXywGz6PRhEX3gYk6bg7r0BfOH8GAHvwPuQ4L12i878vK7EavJFrhTz2SRvyhb9C247kuu4rlMTESdv7pE9CHQezQgbQFCp9OArBowBHpNLLSadM5+1ViwdkoNwaLxXmvZsOhF4xwPkfLQi8z4XyvlVL+GCzYWyOlfTCtDZL+3NqjagoEVxXGACaGk3AACCtgjgTzfIqA6ZVlpYwYZSNBoCRoqWvGHQiH5+h3moKgPoZpXonD4oIXhgQtHn1EOaK+kjEbY1vMMegfRXpgRZAoeAxwTTjG3ijV2-JMA2DnHKBUXhlQeC8EuS49B9TWFsGdBsujCRHBNPOAIYBOgRDkPKYwe9SHmUslpGwn0hxSGjDEOA0oFC6OHh9DgmgN5D0EBgKAgwr70AntPReT0FavV8kPTR+BtGOSnozZwrB2BcHsI4BsKovBC04DwDew4AjRP0SaJcbpipMNvu3YupcH7dXqeNLq1xeH8KEbRURTB-GHVyCHBgER3KSBQQWORdDs4dSUfhcOdsSJqKAZcReMBEhQDEISNyyBioABZDaTRDmGVOqd9Sp39AwYqhsADMhtwXdRXFyZA-IoFT27sAE4ihXzFirGBIUByeBHJERFMRZySZciXFwvEEYaycB4XwilwiXzUspGyw5nKTniO4gwh8kDK4bwxVi7m7g+Y8CTsyrwABxPRsTeUcuOdShGK1LF8jRqqwR-LqWnLVNxEmIqYhQKgQ81hmD0KKK5Mo22REPlYTlYEtUSqYm8IAJJfQ6N0zg+pUB6spVyuQlJ5XuuVbw4NBq5DmzWkdCB5qxVAilZ2Q8sqwJ00EHqBgUyczlk1E2BgqxEihFTqWCALABCaukQm2RGd5GjSmC8m2EdnXqKTtmqAub82uSLf4EtvRy2VurZwH16xjAmgCNkbtvbOAFoHW+UtI7SBVprcKpNFrLDIDTbzDN3AqBAA), also repeated below, there are two examples where wrapping a type with one that includes a superfluous conditional type (that has the *same content* on both branches of the conditional) leads to an unexpected change in behavior (getting rid of the TS(2322) error on line 42) even though the types they directly produce appear the same on hover-inspection.  You can see this for yourself by changing which definition of `TupleToObjectWrapper` and/or `ObjectModel` is commented out.

In theory, adding the superfluous conditional should change nothing, but it makes the code harder to read and follow.
From a debugging perspective, randomly adding type wrappers with superfluous conditionals does not seem like a good strategy, though this shows two instances in which it appears to work.  Why?

A better understanding of why that step works here would enable more reasonable and accurate prediction of when trying the strategy might work in the future, and perhaps a better understanding of the TypeScript behavior which produces the error.

A [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73380275/798371) addresses the apparent need for repetition around `DRYObjectModelMap`.

It is possible this is due to a bug in TypeScript, though not one I can find in the [Issues/PRs list](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=superfluous+conditional) - or maybe I just don't understand what's happening here well enough to search with the right terms or report it.  (Please feel free to file a new bug report there if you think it's appropriate and not duplicative).

---

The code at the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQHJwGZQiOAiARgOwDoArAZ2wG4AoKgeloGVQwAbYVYAUwBM4A3TlFLAI+OBFRxOADxiD8AQxYsAnmmDSecEBG6cWFbQvxqO+7qXEhgMOb1TQ4w8C0FTpCl5yowVYTnAAYlws3EienADqNgAWAGpKAK6cALIKYHAAvHAA3lRwBXApEKIAXHAA2mah4SCc5dh8wMK4rgwwCkIAwhCJ+DDYADTq5gksyeXIALpwAD6V1WERDTEQpDDtnUMjoWMTTjBQwPgA5lPUhXAACizGnDDlVSFLdQ1NLW0d3b3924t79UQSBm8ye5lqgOwq3WNzuA2G-ySgPWR1O5yoAF86LRfP5rrd8PdOioELoVBCsnAANacFQSILPCHRGDxJFpMCGegAcmKoi5czgXNhhJgXMM+Ag8ESpC0DigTmYrnlMk8rG8uICABVEmrNRAAPK4YicADGMAAPJr3HJ8BZKijjidhsYVFMAHyUnKVGlqY5wTUVAAMUym5QAorIoAozZbhhUfc6TO6KgBGGYY6j0AASEAEqJO4jzcBZnBlxYA7hB3KrXKRhiXi35S3BOgEFJYZP4zTxDCW1IStDAq7gAnojgJ7BgsMxoHZG-5SIQfE2iiV8IbjWaU5TtbqDUbTRbguCIszWeNUukKjy11z3ZzaDl3sBWpxNt8+g8gYZoTBhfdygdU4KCxDV8ThDdD23bJd1cPVIJjY8alPWIAXZa9-1Fe84HoJ9mhfT5OlIHpP0mJAfzWDYvkAw5HRAmgwNgzh4IPM1IijMB-CgS1rU4W1LBvPkBSFAl7i5D0YJ1OD903I9GRQlk0KvTV72xABVYRTmLGIAlIHVBFQcZelIABaE1RG4GwREUFh+EEYRRDgEcWAgcs4GOdZOAUXh6QbBRcFzAJKygKk6ycxJ4HLGIVAAfmxRipOYmTD3Y9IuJ4mQbTtQT8H5eYRLhcTKQACitTK+Oy3lcrgGL-USljZPNJCXiiVC2WU904HKJiGsPJr5LqM8lLACoVLdABKahlzxBCYGKPQWAy2QKoEqq8sFTCiskvdZtSzjBEtN1M1oDTHW03T9KgQzEmMsyLKs0QlDsoRrKc-RXPc-BPO88RJD8gKBDgYLQuGXAIqB6K4voMDZvm-Qlqy1bb2EzaJLgUreP4wU1pquqdtYmA9vSzUPW6+rkrYjjiYm46czzM7AvlEsyxgSt6x0tRWxbDtpC7OcADI4AlOc-XMkA6n6SxpTOzhYjcPMHLEelYd0fQcLx6TdqpwRSmmgIqtmgAmSkVYW80cvEh88I+N8vmIn4v2QCiYVEr8gJOeiwMwo2TYJuHFoKkVLZwx9n1fd97dI784F-d8aPzei9bgAARAAlABNU39HZT18kKCpMOJUluBULpblISw-R9elmqZNqL3ZUM4CzxbC6gEkyTL9tSDdPOCnoTUdLely3OBsKwfgYXzpbAHOETXgoE4ABHRJgEXywGz6PRhEX3gYk6bg7r0BfOH8GAHvwPuQ4L12i878vK7EavJFrhTz2SRvyhb9C247kuu4rlMTESdv7pE9CHQezQgbQFCp9OArBowBHpNLLSadM5+1ViwdkoNwaLxXmvZsOhF4xwPkfLQi8z4XyvlVL+GCzYWyOlfTCtDZL+3NqjagoEVxXGACaGk3AACCtgjgTzfIqA6ZVlpYwYZSNBoCRoqWvGHQiH5+h3moKgPoZpXonD4oIXhgQtHn1EOaK+kjEbY1vMMegfRXpgRZAoeAxwTTjG3ijV2-JMA2DnHKBUXhlQeC8EuS49B9TWFsGdBsujCRHBNPOAIYBOgRDkPKYwe9SHmUslpGwn0hxSGjDEOA0oFC6OHh9DgmgN5D0EBgKAgwr70AntPReT0FavV8kPTR+BtGOSnozZwrB2BcHsI4BsKovBC04DwDew4AjRP0SaJcbpipMNvu3YupcH7dXqeNLq1xeH8KEbRURTB-GHVyCHBgER3KSBQQWORdDs4dSUfhcOdsSJqKAZcReMBEhQDEISNyyBioABZDaTRDmGVOqd9Sp39AwYqhsADMhtwXdRXFyZA-IoFT27sAE4ihXzFirGBIUByeBHJERFMRZySZciXFwvEEYaycB4XwilwiXzUspGyw5nKTniO4gwh8kDK4bwxVi7m7g+Y8CTsyrwABxPRsTeUcuOdShGK1LF8jRqqwR-LqWnLVNxEmIqYhQKgQ81hmD0KKK5Mo22REPlYTlYEtUSqYm8IAJJfQ6N0zg+pUB6spVyuQlJ5XuuVbw4NBq5DmzWkdCB5qxVAilZ2Q8sqwJ00EHqBgUyczlk1E2BgqxEihFTqWCALABCaukQm2RGd5GjSmC8m2EdnXqKTtmqAub82uSLf4EtvRy2VurZwH16xjAmgCNkbtvbOAFoHW+UtI7SBVprcKpNFrLDIDTbzDN3AqBAA) is:

```js
import BN from "bn.js";

//Simplified version of externally fixed model; many fields omitted for simpler example
type FieldNameWithValueMap = {
    Moon: [fieldName: "visibleStarsCount", fieldValue: BN] | [fieldName: "hostStar", fieldValue: string];
    Planet: [fieldName: "visibleStarsCount", fieldValue: BN] | [fieldName: "hostPlanet", fieldValue: string];
}
//type PlanetaryBodyName = keyof FieldNameWithValueMap; //'Moon' | 'Planet'; not used for simpler example
type TupleToObject<T extends [string, any]> = { [key in T[0]]: Extract<T, [key, any]>[1] };
//Hovering over these two examples, the types are as expected; they need to be derived from imported types.
type MoonObject1 = TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap['Moon']>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostPlanet: string;}
type PlanetObject1 = TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap['Planet']>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostStar: string;}

type TupleToObjectWrapper<T extends 'Moon' | 'Planet'> = TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap[T]>;
//Using the superfluous-conditional version below instead of the above works, but why?
//type TupleToObjectWrapper<T extends 'Moon' | 'Planet'> = (T extends 'Moon' ? TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap[T]> : TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap[T]>);

type ObjectModel<T extends 'Moon' | 'Planet'> = TupleToObjectWrapper<T>;
//Using the superfluous-conditional version below instead of the above works, but why?
//type ObjectModel<T extends 'Moon' | 'Planet'> = (T extends 'Moon' ? TupleToObjectWrapper<T> : TupleToObjectWrapper<T>);
//Hovering over these two, they are as expected & noted in comments using either version of ObjectModel / TupleToObjectWrapper:
type MoonObject2 = ObjectModel<'Moon'>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostPlanet: string;}
type PlanetObject2 = ObjectModel<'Planet'>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostStar: string;}

type DRYObjectModelMap = {
    [PlanetaryBodyClass in keyof FieldNameWithValueMap]: ObjectModel<PlanetaryBodyClass>
    //The below works, but not the above, and requires the undesired hard-coded repetition
    //[PlanetaryBodyClass in keyof FieldNameWithValueMap]: ObjectModelMap[PlanetaryBodyClass]
}
type ObjectModelMap = { //This works in place of using DRYObjectModelMap, but requires more hard-coded repetition
    Moon: ObjectModel<'Moon'>;
    Planet: ObjectModel<'Planet'>;
}
type PickedAttributeSimpler<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount'];
function genericFunction<
    T extends 'Moon', //union type that includes | 'Planet' omitted for simpler example.
    //Omitting the generic type parameter and hard-coding it into each usage below fixes the error,
    //but the real version of the function not oversimplified for the example needs to be generic.
>(
    PlanetaryBodyClass: T,
) : PickedAttributeSimpler<T> { //Same if using DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount']
    return new BN(42); //ERROR TS(2322): Type 'BN' is not assignable to type 'PickedAttributeSimpler<T>'.
}
type ExamplePickedAttribute = PickedAttributeSimpler<'Moon'>; //This is type 'BN' as expected
type ExampleGenericPickedAttribute<T extends 'Moon'> = PickedAttributeSimpler<T>; //This is DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount']
type ExampleGenericInstanceOfPickedAttribute = ExampleGenericPickedAttribute<'Moon'>; //This is BN as expected
type HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolve<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount'];
type HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolveInstance = HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolve<'Moon'>; //This is BN as expected
```

Comment: Conditionals are distributive. Maybe that can cause some iffies in your code. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/m3XA3W) where it could cause problems (undesirable behavior).

Comment: Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](/help/tagging) to see why adding the tag "superfluous" was ill-advised.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The page you linked to doesn't exist, and I do think there's a category of questions that could be a useful tag on, as described in the tag wiki/excerpt provided.

Comment: Sorry, wrong URL.

Comment: +1 on distributive types. It's not superfluous if it's actually a different type! `Foo<T> = X<T>` is a different type from `Foo<T> = T extends any ? X<T>: X<T>`. Since its distributive, it means T is not a union which means _something_. It's another hint to TS that has some effect in this scenario that I can't parse out.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita & @kelly thanks; opened another question more focused on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389876/798371).  The unexpected behavior seems like a good reason to avoid conditionals here for readability, but omitting them breaks the code. For the reason why, I suspect an interaction with something in the definition of `TupleToObject`, but seeing expected results when hovering over {Moon, Planet}Object{1,2} discounts that hypothesis and instead suggests things should be working to at least those lines in the type construction.