# Why doesn't `T extends B` work to limit T to B in future references?

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-type-argument, generic-type-parameters

In [this TypeScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQHJwGZQiOAiARgOwDoArAZ2wG4AoKgeloGVQwAbYVYAUwBM4A3TlFLAI+OBFRxOADxiD8AQxYsAnmmDSecEBG6cWFbQvxqO+7qXEhgMOb1TQ4w8C0FTpCl5yowVYTnAAYlws3EienADqNgAWAGpKAK6cALIKYHAAvHAA3lRwBXApEKIAXHAA2mah4SCc5dh8wMK4rgwwCkIAwhCJ+DDYADTq5gksyeXIALpwAD6V1WERDTEQpDDtnUMjoWMTTjBQwPgA5lPUhXAACizGnDDlVSFLdQ1NLW0d3b3924t79UQSBm8ye5lqgOwq3WNzuA2G-ySgPWR1O5yoAF86LRfP5rrd8PdOioELoVBCsnAANacFQSILPCHRGDxJFpMCGegAcmKoi5czgXNhhJgXMM+Ag8ESpC0DigTmYrnlMk8rG8uICABVEmrNRAAPK4YicADGMAAPJr3HJ8BZKijjidhsYVFMAHyUnKVGlqY5wTUVAAMUym5QAorIoAozZbhhUfc6TO6KgBGGYY6gauCG41m4p6FiW62cW2WH304LgiLM1njVLpD3ZbW6g1G00Wys1auxAHsiqa93UegACQgAlRJ3E47gLM4MpnAHcIO5Va5SMNZzO-HO4J0AgpLDJ-GaeIZZ2pCVoYMvcAE9EcBPYMFhmNA7Fv-KRCD5t0USvgc3bAAmSlALzXR9HNHl-y5N1OVoHJ3mAVpOE2b4+geIFDGhGBhXucoHVOCgsSzPCYDAmAQOyCj80goUCXuWD4MQ5pkM+TpSB6DDJiQbC1g2L4CMOR1iJ-PEABEACUAE0aIglh2U9fJCgqMjiVJbgVC6W5SEsP1y0kTsXiiHs2XSUNszbcCC3NNSoBJMltIPUg3UxMSAiuYATRpbgAEFbCOXBEjkJgvCgIsZBtO1oL5Rs4Ck2SrJgWiFPSfspgqLkkJQtDOJ+UV0XoTUYgCQQMHlbhmnSfwOLgBcSrETc9A4fAbBEMRbxYCAFzgKNZ3lFljF3XAxwCZo4GlHhv3oUivJ8-zhKCkLFUECLZBLaLeXwWDKQSuSCz7GLtoyrLWJyr48owrl0VQPozXauAThLQQvMCO6YHa81lIKK1Io2ywjq5YZ6D6B6s0G+BjhNcY9EseZ6LhflMBsd85QVMKVy8b9LnofVrFsR0ZxKx7nqOE0PwCMBOgiOR5WMXgYk6bgAFoTV0QmbDgY5rykaMYgm0gFCeuBOu69RNEsTcyugQZvrgeglqJgIoE4JR+EEYRRHESRN1u-B7q1iV4FGoRFXYLh7EcKWPC8OBLztHnbxJwkye-N0AAo5bshzNKc3Tyk1WWAEo4HKTzvJ4BbAuC1CVvCzUPS9egGAiLnJGlQm9qSlK+wHTLsvY9D+muuWVZgRIoDEQkeuQd2ABYgKD+Cw0kyT9Uk-0GHdoCAGYgMbgPfy5ZB+XGo3d104ATkUFCZ2XLMhTmyOAuQmPQrVeO3S5b8SN-CNV04cP5pXpaAmyI-l8Wte46gramPl2hivG8aF5Hif3GPOx3LgfevAAcVJl5C+fkT4xzWlFAGd84rAKjqvZaYVLRwQfk-PSlgs65mSvJXOJ0C6oQulxYuUxv6-zVAAl2XkACS+B1jGBNJwfUqAYGgLkJSEhrgyEvRNEwq+chb4wSQUVGIz9LDIHfkedsPBv6jnHHqBgnBOCjgXJqbcDBViJFCJJOcEAWACHAf9QUUDdoyX2vobB+czqF0uoQzMv5pGCFkfIxRyj-CqN6BorROjOBUJofrM+cA7FQAcQo7qzjUJqPcaQbRujAYCMfkI1BQIxHSE-pIoAA), also repeated below, the type `PickedAttributeSimpler` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with a parameter.  The parameter type is restricted (using `extends`) to a pretty small set - in this example, just one specified possibility, but the restriction doesn't have to always be so narrow.

Later in the type definition, I would expect that references to the generic type parameter would be narrowed to the type the parameter was restricted to, i.e. what's on the right side of the `extends` keyword.  In any particular use context, it might even be narrower.  However, in this example and in several more complicated ones eventually boiled down to this one, replacing references to the type parameter with the type that parameter is limited to (to the right of `extends`) produced the desired behavior, allowing TypeScript to figure out the type of the generic as a whole.

Unfortunately, in practice, some additional narrowing is sometimes needed, where an instance of the type specifies a parameter more specific than the type that parameter must be limited to, and additional references to the generic type parameter are needed to track that through consistently - so just dropping the use of generic type parameters altogether is not a valid solution beyond this simplified example.

Instead, a better understanding is sought of the conditions in which limiting the parameter type will NOT result in later references to the generic type parameter reflecting that narrowing.

Separate questions address why some simplifications that appear possible from this example such as [hard-coding the ObjectModelMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73380275/798371) or [using a conditional type in ObjectModel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379880/798371) don't adequately preserve the issue being demonstrated.

It is possible this is due to a bug in TypeScript. The closest issue I could find is [#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) but that seems to be more specific about functions than defining other types.  Maybe I just don't understand what's happening here well enough to search with the right terms or report it.  (Please feel free to file a new bug report there if you think it's appropriate and not duplicative).

---

The code at the [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQHJwGZQiOAiARgOwDoArAZ2wG4AoKgeloGVQwAbYVYAUwBM4A3TlFLAI+OBFRxOADxiD8AQxYsAnmmDSecEBG6cWFbQvxqO+7qXEhgMOb1TQ4w8C0FTpCl5yowVYTnAAYlws3EienADqNgAWAGpKAK6cALIKYHAAvHAA3lRwBXApEKIAXHAA2mah4SCc5dh8wMK4rgwwCkIAwhCJ+DDYADTq5gksyeXIALpwAD6V1WERDTEQpDDtnUMjoWMTTjBQwPgA5lPUhXAACizGnDDlVSFLdQ1NLW0d3b3924t79UQSBm8ye5lqgOwq3WNzuA2G-ySgPWR1O5yoAF86LRfP5rrd8PdOioELoVBCsnAANacFQSILPCHRGDxJFpMCGegAcmKoi5czgXNhhJgXMM+Ag8ESpC0DigTmYrnlMk8rG8uICABVEmrNRAAPK4YicADGMAAPJr3HJ8BZKijjidhsYVFMAHyUnKVGlqY5wTUVAAMUym5QAorIoAozZbhhUfc6TO6KgBGGYY6gauCG41m4p6FiW62cW2WH304LgiLM1njVLpD3ZbW6g1G00Wys1auxAHsiqa93UegACQgAlRJ3E47gLM4MpnAHcIO5Va5SMNZzO-HO4J0AgpLDJ-GaeIZZ2pCVoYMvcAE9EcBPYMFhmNA7Fv-KRCD5t0USvgc3bAAmSlALzXR9HNHl-y5N1OVoHJ3mAVpOE2b4+geIFDGhGBhXucoHVOCgsSzPCYDAmAQOyCj80goUCXuWD4MQ5pkM+TpSB6DDJiQbC1g2L4CMOR1iJ-PEABEACUAE0aIglh2U9fJCgqMjiVJbgVC6W5SEsP1y0kTsXiiHs2XSUNszbcCC3NNSoBJMltIPUg3UxMSAiuYATRpbgAEFbCOXBEjkJgvCgIsZBtO1oL5Rs4Ck2SrJgWiFPSfspgqLkkJQtDOJ+UV0XoTUYgCQQMHlbhmnSfwOLgBcSrETc9A4fAbBEMRbxYCAFzgKNZ3lFljF3XAxwCZo4GlHhv3oUivJ8-zhKCkLFUECLZBLaLeXwWDKQSuSCz7GLtoyrLWJyr48owrl0VQPozXauAThLQQvMCO6YHa81lIKK1Io2ywjq5YZ6D6B6s0G+BjhNcY9EseZ6LhflMBsd85QVMKVy8b9LnofVrFsR0ZxKx7nqOE0PwCMBOgiOR5WMXgYk6bgAFoTV0QmbDgY5rykaMYgm0gFCeuBOu69RNEsTcyugQZvrgeglqJgIoE4JR+EEYRRHESRN1u-B7q1iV4FGoRFXYLh7EcKWPC8OBLztHnbxJwkye-N0AAo5bshzNKc3Tyk1WWAEo4HKTzvJ4BbAuC1CVvCzUPS9egGAiLnJGlQm9qSlK+wHTLsvY9D+muuWVZgRIoDEQkeuQd2ABYgKD+Cw0kyT9Uk-0GHdoCAGYgMbgPfy5ZB+XGo3d104ATkUFCZ2XLMhTmyOAuQmPQrVeO3S5b8SN-CNV04cP5pXpaAmyI-l8Wte46gramPl2hivG8aF5Hif3GPOx3LgfevAAcVJl5C+fkT4xzWlFAGd84rAKjqvZaYVLRwQfk-PSlgs65mSvJXOJ0C6oQulxYuUxv6-zVAAl2XkACS+B1jGBNJwfUqAYGgLkJSEhrgyEvRNEwq+chb4wSQUVGIz9LDIHfkedsPBv6jnHHqBgnBOCjgXJqbcDBViJFCJJOcEAWACHAf9QUUDdoyX2vobB+czqF0uoQzMv5pGCFkfIxRyj-CqN6BorROjOBUJofrM+cA7FQAcQo7qzjUJqPcaQbRujAYCMfkI1BQIxHSE-pIoAA) is:

```js
import BN from "bn.js";

//Simplified version of externally fixed model; many fields omitted for simpler example
type FieldNameWithValueMap = {
    Moon: [fieldName: "visibleStarsCount", fieldValue: BN] | [fieldName: "hostStar", fieldValue: string];
    Planet: [fieldName: "visibleStarsCount", fieldValue: BN] | [fieldName: "hostPlanet", fieldValue: string];
}
//type PlanetaryBodyName = keyof FieldNameWithValueMap; //'Moon' | 'Planet'; not used for simpler example
type TupleToObject<T extends [string, any]> = { [key in T[0]]: Extract<T, [key, any]>[1] };
type ObjectModel<T extends keyof FieldNameWithValueMap> = TupleToObject<FieldNameWithValueMap[T]>;
//Hovering over these two examples, the types are as expected; they need to be derived from imported types.
type MoonObject2 = ObjectModel<'Moon'>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostPlanet: string;}
type PlanetObject2 = ObjectModel<'Planet'>; //{visibleStarsCount: BN; hostStar: string;}
type DRYObjectModelMap = {
    [PlanetaryBodyClass in keyof FieldNameWithValueMap]: ObjectModel<PlanetaryBodyClass>
}
type PickedAttributeSimpler<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount'];
//The error disappears when the definition below rather than above is used.
//type PickedAttributeSimpler<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap['Moon']['visibleStarsCount'];
function genericFunction<
    T extends 'Moon', //union type that includes | 'Planet' omitted for simpler example.
    //Omitting the generic type parameter and hard-coding it into each usage below fixes the error,
    //but the real version of the function not oversimplified for the example needs to be generic.
>(
    PlanetaryBodyClass: T,
) : PickedAttributeSimpler<T> { //Same if using DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount']
    return new BN(42); //ERROR TS(2322): Type 'BN' is not assignable to type 'PickedAttributeSimpler<T>'.
}
type ExamplePickedAttribute = PickedAttributeSimpler<'Moon'>; //This is type 'BN' as expected
type ExampleGenericPickedAttribute<T extends 'Moon'> = PickedAttributeSimpler<T>; //This is DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount']
type ExampleGenericInstanceOfPickedAttribute = ExampleGenericPickedAttribute<'Moon'>; //This is BN as expected
type HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolve<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount'];
type HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolveInstance = HoverToSeeHowTypeShouldResolve<'Moon'>; //This is BN as expected
```

Comment: I've read most of your posts and I can't answer them but I do feel the same questions re: TS. I've found that TS generics are a completely different animal and have a lot more unintuitive layers like 2 pass inference, distributive types, unintuitive code flow (e.g. code downstream of a conditional affects the overall types). Replacing a generic type with the hard coded "equivalent" is not fruitful. As for this q, T extends B only guarantees compatibility with B and does not inform the type of T. `Fn<T extends { a: 123 }> = T....`  T on the right side can be any type that is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, typescript is a little bit wierd sometimes.

If you use a mapped type of a Union to look up the type value it's working. It would also work with just "Moon", btw.
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=26&pln=30&pc=34#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQHJwGZQiOAiARgOwDoArAZ2wG4AoAehoGVQwAbYVYAUwBM4A3DqKWAR8cCKjgcAHjAH4Ahs2YBPNMCnc4ICFw7MKW+flXs9XUmJDAYsnqmhwh4ZgMlT5zjlRjKwHOABinMxcSB4cAOrWABYAaooArhwAsvJgcAC8cADeVHD5cMkQIgBccADapiFhIBxl2LzAQrgu9DDyggDCEAn4MNgANGpm8cxJZcgAunAAPhVVoeH10RCkMG0dg8Mho+OOMFDA+ADmk9QFcAAKzEYcMGWVwYu19Y3Nre1dPX1bC7t1iCQ0zmjzMNQB2BWa2ut36Qz+iQBa0OJzOVAAvrQaD4-Fcbvg7h1lAgdMpwZk4ABrDjKcSBJ7gqIwOKI1JgAx0ADkRREnNmcE5MIJME5BnwEHgCVImnsUEcTBccukHhYXhx-gAKglVRqIAB5XDEDgAYxgAB4NW5ZPhzBVkUdjkMjMpJgA+CnZCrU1RHOAa8oABkmkzKAFEZFB5KaLUNyt6ncY3eUAIzTdHUdVwA1G01FXTMC1Wjg2izeulBMHhJkssYpNLurJanX6w0m80V6pVmL-NnlDVu6h0AASEH4KOOYjHcGZHGl04A7hA3CqXKQhjPp75Z3AOv55BZpH5TdwDDPVATNDAl7h-LpDvw7BgsExoLZN35SIRvFvCsV8Nm2wAJgpADcx0PQzW5P9OVdDkaGyN5gBaDgNi+Xp7kBAwoRgIU7jKe0TgoTFM1wmBQJgYCsnIvMIMFfE7hguCEKaJCPg6UhunQiYkCw1Z1k+fCDgdIjv1xAARAAlABNajwOYNkPTyApylIokSS4ZROhuUgLF9MsJA7Z5Im7Vk0hDLNWzA-MzVUqBiVJLT91IV0MVE-xLmAY1qS4ABBGxDlwBJZEYTwoELaRrVtABVfBhHwBs4EkmTLJgGj5LSPtJnKTlEOQ1COO+EU0TcuAYriilsB5fBsBmbBSOwEq2T8HgsmycoAGk4F9MqRBDDyvO4PyhMC4KFQEM12tdTEsQ1aJ-AEDA5S4Jo0j8di4HnObRA3XR2FimBypvZgIHnOBIxnOVmSMHdcFHfwmjgKVuC-OgSM87yhoCoKULGsLLQi4tbSg3kEqS2T817YH8E5LKcpYvLPgK9CYeoVBelNcrjmLARPICdGDpEM0lPyf6ZEBiwevwIY6F6crMyu+AjmNMZdAsOY6NhPlMGsN9ZXlULl08L8LjoPUrBsB1pzmuAsYJQ5jXffwwA6cJZDlIweGiDouAAWmNHRJesLq+iXDgo2iR7SHkLG4COk61A0CwNwW6ABmJuA6BGqX-CgM3mD4AQhBEMQJA3NH8Ax4PxXgO7BAVNhODsBxnfcTw4AvW0r1t-xZZx40v1dAAKd3bPsjTHJ0soNTdgBKOAyia7hMpyD2GHCLqJClSWwZStLe37bLcrYtC+hh93fZgBIoFEAlTuQQuABZAJruCkFNqBFs5L9pszcMVw4fqPv8pDvopQ-BuPkaftCyCqsY1vZoeh7M05ZA+X3Nwj1sEq988ABxbG8tz6+Uvt9cKZMSwCjvglYBn0T6jRvhqWCD9ohPwsD3HMqU5L91hkPFCiNOKj0mD-VOqoAFy08gASXwGsIwxoOB6lQLA0BsgKS-zIYAzyzDhpgKhvfOgj9dIWGQDuA8Ugv7cBKiOMcup6AcA4COecGotz0BWAkEIElZwQGYPwcBkULB8NBtJcGegcGD3hsPJGRCMw-mkQIWR8jFHKL8KonoGitE6I4NQ2hEd-BZDsVABxCiTrOJQmo9xpBtG6MMXBQRXVhEoA-oeNskigA)

```
type Union = "Moon"|"Planet"
type Mapped = {[K in Union]:PickedAttributeSimpler<K>}

//The error disappears when the definition below rather than above is used.
//type PickedAttributeSimpler<T extends 'Moon'> = DRYObjectModelMap['Moon']['visibleStarsCount'];
function genericFunction<
    T extends Union, //union type that includes | 'Planet' omitted for simpler example.
    //Omitting the generic type parameter and hard-coding it into each usage below fixes the error,
    //but the real version of the function not oversimplified for the example needs to be generic.
>(
    PlanetaryBodyClass: T,
) : Mapped[T] { //Same if using DRYObjectModelMap[T]['visibleStarsCount']
    return new BN(42); //No error
}
```