# What's a good way to conceptualize/remember `X<T> != T extends any ? X<T>: X<T>`?

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-statements, typescript-generics

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379880/why-can-adding-a-superfluous-conditional-change-typescripts-compilation?noredirect=1#comment129592394_73379880),
Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita helpfully points out that in TypeScript,
"`Foo<T> = X<T>` is a different type from `Foo<T> = T extends any ? X<T>: X<T>`."
This is true, as illustrated in Kelly's [example](https://tsplay.dev/m3XA3W) from an earlier comment on the same post.
However, it's unexpected and unintuitive that having a conditional with the same content on each branch should be different from having just that content without the conditional.
For example, suppose one were to encounter the following in JavaScript (or even TypeScript):

```js
if(booleanVar) {
    takeSpecificActions();
} else {
    takeSpecificActions(); //same as above
}
```

That is functionally exactly the same as, and less preferred for maintainability reasons compared to:

```js
takeSpecificActions();
```

Changing from the first to the second would be a useful maintainability improvement for someone going through to improve code quality and readability.  However, in TypeScript's types, consolidating matching conditional branches like this can lead to breaking downstream code that uses these types in unexpected places and ways, as illustrated by [the post those comments were on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73379880/798371).

What is a good way to conceptualize how and why `X<T> != T extends any ? X<T>: X<T>`?
A great answer would enhance understanding in a way that makes this difference more intuitive, easier to remember, and easier to teach to TypeScript newcomers.

Comment: Well first of all, you probably wouldn't write it as `T extends any ? X<T> : X<T>`. The "else" branch would never be reached so you would rather write `T extends any ? X<T> : never`, or `T extends T ? X<T> : never`.

Comment: I prefer `T extends T` when using this kind of conditional because it makes it clear that it's different than the "usual" conditional. And also I think `T extends T` somehow, maybe its just that my brain is hotwired this way, but somehow it always makes me think "distributive".

Comment: Oh, here is a Stack Overflow question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382306/typescript-distributive-conditional-types

Comment: @kelly thanks for the comment, but I think that focuses on an artifact of simplification and misses the main point about how adding a conditional that appears completely superfluous actually changes code behavior in unexpected ways. `T extends T` reads like it should similarly always evaluate true, leading to the same conclusion that the second branch shouldn't be reached, but raises more questions about possible strange interactions with reuse of the generic type parameter.

Comment: Personally, I didn't understand this either, but over time I just got used to it and I can "sniff" out TypeScript's behavior, as if I was some neural network trained to predict it. And if you think about it, it's like asking why we use `=` to assign values when in mathematics it means "equal", so we come up with monstrosities like `===` to denote "equal", and even then it isn't a deep-equal. But I'm sure someone else will have an intuitive explanation.

Comment: I think the way to conceptualize it is that it just is. Its a feature of the language https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types and we are free to use it and must know about it. A good way to remember this behavior, is maybe to think about the use cases. I just answered a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392265/how-can-i-get-the-keys-from-an-object-that-is-union-as-shared that I used distributive conditionals to operate on a union.

Comment: The docs have a pretty intuitive use case: `ToArray<string | MyType> returning string[] | MyType[]` so distributive being typically desirable, but also shows ways to disable this behavior for when it's not desirable and do want T passed as union.